# Obtaining bounds on a Normal Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

> Question: Over a period of 6 months, customers were surveyed and the
>   amount of downtime (in minutes) they had experienced during the
>   previous month was collected. The average downtime was found to be
>   25.09 min with a variance of 144.

(a) Obtain bounds that will include 95 % of the downtime of all the customers.

This is what I came up with so far using the IQR method. 95% of 25.09 is 23.8355.

$23.8355 = (X*Standard Deviation)+Mean = (X * 12)+25.09$

So X = -.1045416 and using the Z-table, I got the bound to be 0.45837.

I really have no idea how to solve this problem. If you could explain and help me with part a, I'm sure I can do part b alone. Thank you.

(b) Obtain the bound above which 10% of the downtime is included.

Comment: "(a) Obtain bounds that will include 95 % of the downtime of all the customers." This is a very poorly formulated question. Which 95%? Central? Bottom 95%? Top? Some odd offset interval?

Comment: @SeanLake: I copied and pasted the question off the textbook so I really don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use your tables, first you should normalize $X$,

$$
Z = \frac{X - \mu_X}{\sigma_X} ~~~\Leftrightarrow~~~ X = \sigma_X Z + \mu_X \tag{1}
$$

Now you can recast the question as: What is the value of $z$ such that the area under the pdf between $-z$ and $+z$ is 0.95? Since the pdf is symmetric around the mean, this is equivalent to find $z$ such that the area between $0$ and $+z$ is 0.475. By looking at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table) table you find that

$$
z = 1.96
$$

That is, the area under $-1.96 < z < 1.96$ is 0.95. By using Eq. (1) you get

$$
1.57\;{\rm min} < x < 48.61\;{\rm min}
$$

As for the (b) part, you need to repeat pretty much the same exercise, but now considering the tails instead. Since now the tails enclose 10% of the area, then you are looking for $z$ such that the area under the pdf between $-z$ and $z$ is now 0.9

$$
z = 1.64
$$

which leads to

$$
5.41\;{\rm min} < x < 44.77\;{\rm min}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for a really great explanation! It makes so much more sense now.